# Why are these variable fields Automatically becoming NULL values in json parsing task.

Tags: c#, json, parsing, null

My goal is to get data values out from the json data in this url: 
http://someeu.altinget.dk/json.php?q=0&d=24&s=0&src=fb&g=1&l=200

I got the json data into the object called SoMedata and are trying to create loops that parse through the data and write ceratin parts of the json data out.

Inside the second loop the field variable's field always instantly becomes Null every time I assign a value from one of the fields in field or compare one of the field values in field to a value.

What do I do to solve this problem? It might have something to do with field being an array and where SoMedata is an object.

```
using altinget.code;
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using Altinget.Extensions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;



namespace Altinget7.Controls
{
public partial class SoMeDebateBox : BaseControl
{
   public string titleTooltip = "Ukendt indtil videre";
   public static string link = "http://someeu.altinget.dk/json.php?q=0&d=24&s=0&src=fb&g=1&l=200";
   public string title = "Skal hentes fra resourcer";



   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //SoMetextOut.Text = "<link rel = \"stylesheet\" href=\"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css\">";
       Page.Trace.Write("Render Time", "DebateBox Start");
       var web = new WebClient();
       var output = web.DownloadString(link);
       dynamic SoMedata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(output);        
       dynamic contentData;
       dynamic checkvar;         
       SoMetextOut.Text = " <h3> Danske EU - parlamentarikere på Facebook</h3>";
       foreach (var item in SoMedata)
       {             
            if (item.Name == "content")
           {                 
                contentData = item.First;
               foreach (var field in contentData)
               {
                    checkvar = contentData.First;
                    checkvar = field;
                    checkvar = field.First;
                    if (field.First.Name == "author_full_name")
                   {
                       SoMetextOut.Text += " field.value";
                   }
               }

               SoMetextOut.Text += "<li>" + SoMedata.status.ToString() + "</li>";
           }
       }

       SoMetextOut.Text = " <h3> Danske EU - parlamentarikere på Facebook</h3>";
       SoMetextOut.Text += " <h6>Indlæg fra de seneste 24 timer sorteret efter flest interaktioner</h6>";
       SoMetextOut.Text += "<div class=\"card mt-1 w-100\" style=\"background-color:#FFFFFF;box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px 0px rgba(0.75,0.75,0.75,0.75)\">";  //background-color:#d7bde2;
       SoMetextOut.Text += "<div class=\"card-block\" style=\"padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px\">";
       SoMetextOut.Text += "<ul>";
       SoMetextOut.Text += "<li>" + SoMedata.status.ToString() + "</li>";
       SoMetextOut.Text += "<li>" + SoMedata.template.ToString() + "</li>";
       SoMetextOut.Text += "<li>" + SoMedata.id.ToString() + "</li>";
       SoMetextOut.Text += "<li>" + SoMedata.title.ToString() + "</li>";
       SoMetextOut.Text += "</ul> </div> </div>";
        //lit.Text = String.Format("<div class=""{1}"">{0}</div>", InnerText, CssClass)
        // Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty jProperty = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty(field);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly are you trying to read from the json?

Comment: From this url: http://someeu.altinget.dk/json.php?q=0&d=24&s=0&src=fb&g=1&l=200    I wanna read: "title" ,"subtitle", "author_full_name", "post_message" and "post_link".

Answer (score 0):

You can base your code from this:

```
var data = JObject.Parse(json);

var status = (string)data["status"];
// ...

foreach(var content in data["content"])
{
    var fullname = (string)content["author_full_name"];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I already did that. The problem is that I get an object with property variable inside which make it more complicated.